# asymptotic expansion of exponential solution to ODE

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics

Obtain the first two terms of the asymptotic (large x) solution for each of the 2 real solutions of 
$$u''+\left ( 1-\frac{\gamma}{x^{2}} \right )u=0$$ in $$x> 4$$

Now,
For large x, the above equation reduces to $$u_{0}''+u_{0}=0$$
Solving gives $$u_{0}=C_{1}cos\left ( x \right )+C_{2}Sin\left ( x \right )$$
converting to exponential form yields $$\left\{\left\{u_{0}\to \frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{-i x}+\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{i x}+\frac{1}{2} i c_2
   e^{-i x}-\frac{1}{2} i c_2 e^{i x}\right\}\right\}$$

Dropping the imaginary and the non-decaying terms we get

$$u_{0}=\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{-i x}+\ $$
Now, the 'real' solution to the original equation is of the form
$$u=u_{0}+u_{1} where u_{0}\gg u_{1}$$

Any help is appreciated. What am I missing?

Comment: $$u_{0}=C_{1}\cos\left ( x \right )+C_{2}\sin\left ( x \right )=ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}$$

Comment: You basically combined terms where a and b are some groups of coefficients.
Now, dropping the positive power on exponential, we're left with the negative power on exponential .

Comment: why shall you drop the positive one?

Comment: For a large $x$ your solution will behave as $e^x$ which looks fine to me. However, you do have two linearly independent solutions, though...

Comment: Do I leave the solution as it is then? Could you elaborate?@MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: I don't think this is answers the question that you ask here.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I'm not getting the big picture. Can you elaborate? That is all.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I'm really puzzled why are we preserving the positive exponential power...

Comment: I think I see why
If it were negative, then the second term would be greater than the third so it does not make sense.

Comment: Well, now I think that you should stay with $a\cos x+b\sin x$ solution - this is clearly represent the oscillating behavior of the solution at the infinity (a.k.a asymptotic behavior).

Comment: What is known about $\gamma$ ?

Comment: What is known about $\gamma$ ? Especially, is $\gamma$ larger or smaller than or equal to $-\frac{1}{4}$ ? "Dropping the imaginary and the non-decaying terms ..." results in dropping terms proportional to  $\exp(i\, x)$ (and other terms) in your question, which are neither purely imaginary nor decaying (assuming $x$ is real as $x>4$ seems to imply). I am not getting the question.

Comment: $$\gamma$$ is some dam constant. It is obvious. The exams are over and I shall spend some time thinking about this if possible.